# SharePoint 2010 calendar month view - show more entries

Tags: 2010, calendar, view, sharepoint-calendar

Good morning!

I like the month view of my calendar which my team finds very useful. However, where there's multiple items in a day, not all of these show and you need to click the '1 more item' or '2 more items' link to show the additional entries.

The only place I can see where you can edit the amount of entries showing is under the mobile view settings in the Modify view area.

Is there anyway of showing upto 5 entries in the month view?